# Pandas Pivot on one column with multindex

Tags: python, pandas

i want to pivot a table based on one column and with index as two columns,

Dataset:

```
uid     interaction date
1       like        2016-12-04
1       like        2016-12-05
1       comment     2016-12-05
1       like        2016-12-05
2       like        2016-12-04
2       like        2016-12-05
2       comment     2016-12-05
2       like        2016-12-05
```

using uid and date  i want to the number  of interaction happened for the particular uid on the particular date.

final result:

```
uid     like    comment  date
1       1       0       2016-12-04
1       2       1       2016-12-05
2       1       0       2016-12-04
2       2       1       2016-12-05
```

Approach which i tried:

```
doc_social_interaction.pivot_table(index = ['uid','date'],columns = 'interaction', aggfunc=sum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['uid','date'],columns='interaction',aggfunc='size',fill_value=0)
```

Another solutions:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['uid','date','interaction']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

df1 = df.groupby(['uid','date'])['interaction'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

df1 = pd.crosstab([df['uid'],df['date']], df['interaction'])

print (df1)
interaction     comment  like
uid date                     
1   2016-12-04        0     1
    2016-12-05        1     2
2   2016-12-04        0     1
    2016-12-05        1     2
```

Last some data cleaning:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)
print (df1)
   uid        date  comment  like
0    1  2016-12-04        0     1
1    1  2016-12-05        1     2
2    2  2016-12-04        0     1
3    2  2016-12-05        1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: (My dataframe name is test)

Step 1: add a constant:

```
test['constant'] =1
pd.pivot_table(test, index=['uid', 'date'], columns='interaction', values='constant', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)

    interaction     comment     like
uid     date        
1       2016-12-04   0.0        1.0
        2016-12-05   1.0        2.0
2       2016-12-04   0.0        1.0
        2016-12-05   1.0        2.0
```